# Issues Making a simple timeline with moment JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, momentjs

Im trying to create a simple report where I get entries from an ajax request and I want to simply group my entries by the day of the week. For example I want to come out something simple as:

```
----------------------------------
Monday - May 2nd - 2016
-----------------------------------
Entry 1 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 09:45
-----------------------------------
Entry 2 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 10:55
-----------------------------------

-----------------------------------
Tuesday - May 3rd - 2016
-----------------------------------
No entries to display ...
-----------------------------------


-----------------------------------
Wednesday - May 4th - 2016
-----------------------------------
Entry 3 
Description
Date: 2016-05-04 09:45
-----------------------------------
Entry 4 
Description
Date: 2016-05-04 10:55
----------------------------------
```

I am currently stuck on one part of the code which is, if there are no entries for the day then return:

```
$('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2">No entries to display...</td></tr>');
```

Is there a way to simply say if the day of the weeks entry length is equal to 0 then return the above?

This is what I have at the moment, it's a bit of a mess at the moment cause ive been trying so many things.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLdn68ko/20/

```
  var items_by_date  = {}; // declare an object that will have date indexes
  $.ajax({url:"/SomeUrlBeginninWithSlash",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        data.d.results.map(function(item){

        var minDate = moment("2016-05-02");
        var maxDate = moment("2016-05-04");
        var duration = moment(minDate).diff(moment(maxDate), 'days');

        while(duration > 0){
          item_date = moment(minDate).format('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
          // if the date index does not exist we need to declare it
          if(!items_by_date[item_date]) items_by_date[item_date] = [item];
          // else we can just push the item on that array
          else items_by_date[item_date].push(item);    
          var minDate = moment(minDate).subtract(1, 'day');
          var duration_test = duration_test-1;
        }
       console.log(items_by_date); 

       })
        drawTable(items_by_date);
      }
  });

  function drawTable(data){
    $('#dataTable').html('');
    Object.keys(data).sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a)-new Date(b)}).forEach(function(d){
        $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">'+d+'</td></tr>');
        data[d].map(function(item){
              if(item.ID == ""){
                $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2">No entries to display...</td></tr>');
            }else{
                $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>'+item.ID+'</td><td>'+item.Description+'</td></tr>');                
            }
        })
      })
  }
```

Here is an example of my ajax request

```
responseText: {
    d: {
        results: [{
            ID: "1",
            Description: "Test1",
            Date: "2016-05-02 09:45"
        }, {
            ID: "2",
            Description: "Test2",
            Date: "2016-05-02 10:45"
        }, {
            ID: "3",
            Description: "Test3",
            Date: "2016-05-04 11:45"
        }, {
            ID: "4",
            Description: "Test4",
            Date: "2016-05-04 11:45",
        }]
    }
}
```

Would anyone have any idea what im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got carried away and rewrote the whole thing.  Sorry about that.

This doesn't require precalculating arrays of entries for each day.  Instead, the strategy is to loop through days, keeping track of which entries have already been displayed as an efficiency shortcut:

- For each date in the range,

  - If the next undisplayed entry is later than this date, show "no entries today" and move on to the next date.
  - Otherwise, starting after the last already-displayed entry, show all entries before the end of the current date.

(For any reasonable number of entries a plain old boring nested loop would probably have been perfectly sufficient, but premature optimization is much more fun.)

```js
var drawTable = function(data) {
  // First sort the entries by date:
  data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (moment(a.Date) - moment(b.Date));
  });

  // Find the date range to work with by looking at each end of the array:
  var firstDate = moment(data[0].Date);
  var lastDate = moment(data[data.length - 1].Date).endOf('day');

  // loop through each day in that range, keeping track of a starting point i
  // so we don't have to keep checking already-passed events.
  var i = 0, // pointer to the first entry to check on the next date
    ret = ""; 
  for (var thisDate = firstDate; thisDate <= lastDate; thisDate.add(1, 'days')) {
    ret += '<tr><th>' + thisDate.format("dddd, MMMM D") + "</th></tr>";
    
    // check to see if the next entry is already beyond thisDate:
    if (moment(data[i].Date) > thisDate.endOf('day')) {
      ret += "<tr><td>No entries today.</td></tr>";
    } else {
      // starting at entry i, display all entries before the end of thisDate:
      for (var j = i; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (moment(data[j].Date) < thisDate.endOf('day')) {
          // the next one belongs on thisDate, so display it:
          ret += '<tr><td>' + moment(data[j].Date).format("HH:mm") + " - " + data[j].Description + "</td></tr>";
        } else {
          // next one is not for thisDate, so we can go on to the next day.
          i = j; // It'll start here, so we don't waste time looping over past events
          break; // (out of the inner loop)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $('#x').html(ret);
}

// hardcoding test data instead of using ajax for demo, with some 
// repeated and some out-of-order events:

drawTable(
  [{
    ID: "1",
    Description: "Test 1",
    Date: "2016-05-06 09:45"
  }, {
    ID: "2",
    Description: "Test 2",
    Date: "2016-05-02 10:45"
  }, {
    ID: "3",
    Description: "Test 3",
    Date: "2016-05-04 11:45"
  }, {
    ID: "4",
    Description: "Test 4",
    Date: "2016-05-04 11:45",
  }, {
    ID: "5",
    Description: "Test 5",
    Date: "2016-05-04 12:45",
  }]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

<table id="x"></table>
```

Comment: Wow thanks Daniel. Just curios to know how to make this work with an ajax request. I copied your code in a jsfiddle but getting errors that sort is undefidned https://jsfiddle.net/vLdn68ko/21/ would you know what the issue might me?

Comment: Looks like mockjax stops working as of jQuery 2.2.0, rollback fixes it.  Also call `drawTable(data.d.results)` instead of just `data`: https://jsfiddle.net/j3yg2j7j/1/

Comment: Ah thank you so much Daniel, its working much better now.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I opened up a new question to follow up on some new issues I found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300449/moment-jquery-silly-issue-with-a-simple-timeline I would love your help when you get a chance.